# Specifying returnUrl with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to provide a returnUrl with Azure AD B2C so that after login or registration, the user is sent back to the specified URL if one is provided?

In my app, users can send invitations to each other or new users. These invitations are handled at a specific URL that contains an `invitationId` e.g. `https://myapp.com/invitation/48bbc1e5-dfa2-42cd-9afa-acb362415e03`. If a new user receives this, I'd like the user to come back to this URL after registering through Azure AD B2C so that I can pick up and process this invitation.

Is this something I can do with Azure AD B2C?

BTW: My app is an ASP.NET Core SPA app with React front end so I'm using `MSAL` library to handle redirecting to Azure AD B2C and handling of `jwt` tokens.

Comment: Be aware that you might get issues if you put the invitationId into the route. B2C requires you to set up all possible reply urls beforehand. You will probably need to store your Id in the session state or similar

Answer (score 2):

If an unauthenticated user opens `https://myapp.com/invitation/48bbc1e5-dfa2-42cd-9afa-acb362415e0`, then the MSAL library should return the authenticated user to this same URL after handling the authentication response that is received from Azure AD B2C.

It does by [writing the current URL to storage](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/3932741cf18a4cf5d8606768da6925aa41420915/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L350) before it sends the authentication request to Azure AD B2C:

```
this._cacheStorage.setItem(Constants.loginRequest, window.location.href);
```

and then [reading the original URL from storage](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/3932741cf18a4cf5d8606768da6925aa41420915/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L1339) after it receives the authentication response from Azure AD B2C:

```
window.location.href = self._cacheStorage.getItem(Constants.loginRequest);
```